# why is console logging this is undefined with react?

Tags: reactjs, undefined, this

I recently came back to coding and I'm trying learn react on udemy. this code should fetch json files from a website and console.log them. instead I'm getting a this is undefined error.how do I get it to correctly log the information from the fetched website and remove this is undefined error?

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component() {
  
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state ={
monsters:[],
    };
  }
  
 componentDidMount(){
   fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then((response)=>response.json()).then((users)=>console.log(users));
 }
render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
    );
}}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is the actual error coming from? And what is the actual error message?

Comment: Issue is in class definition, it should be:
`class App extends Component` (without round brackets).

Comment: this resolved the issue, thank you, i am new and learning and to answer the other question this is the entire error.....                                                                   Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined
    Component React
    js App.js:6
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 7
react.development.js:313
    Component React
    js App.js:6
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 7

Answer (score 2):

Try this, We can use function component and hooks nowadays because it is easy to use and redable to others.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response)=>response.json())
  .then((users)=>console.log(users));
 }, []);

return (
 <div className='App'>
   <h1>Hello React.</h1>
   <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
 </div>
);
}

export default App;
```